# How to change an image with a "viewWithTag" programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewwithtag

I'm currently working with nibs need to change the images based on their tag programmatically based on country.  I've tried:

```
vc.view.viewWithTag(8).image = UIImage(named:"image")
```

but it throws an error "Value of type UIView has no member image", any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewWithTag` will give **UIView** in return. But you need **ImageView** type. So you need to explicitly cast it and assign the image.

```
if let imgView = vc.view.viewWithTag(8) as? UIImageView {
    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "image")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the view. I'm on mobile but it's something like this:

```
if let imageView = vc.view.viewWithTag(8) as? UIImageView {
 // Stuff here 
}
```